# How to plot confusion matrix correctly

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

Does anyone know how I can plot confusion matrix for 100 class labels? I did these line of codes but I ended up having a confusion matrix attached. The code is working fine for less class numbers like 5 but as the number of classes is 100, there in no clear confusion matrix.
[image]

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
confmat = confusion_matrix(y_true=y_test, y_pred=y_pred)
print(confmat)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
ax.matshow(confmat, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, alpha=0.3)
for i in range(confmat.shape[0]):
    for j in range(confmat.shape[1]):
        ax.text(x=j, y=i, s=confmat[i, j], va='center', ha='center')
plt.xlabel('predicted label')
plt.ylabel('true label')
plt.show()
```

Comment: you might try `ax.imshow(cm, cmap='gist_heat')`